# How to call a javascript function inside another function in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have a file `index.js` as below. Where I am trying to call a async function `getConn` in other function `createThumbnails`. But I am getting the error as `"failed to connect to DEDC: 1433 - self signed certificate"` in the catch block.

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
const sql = require('mssql')

// CONNECTION CONFIGURATION OF BASE DB
async function getConn() {
    try {
        const config = {
            user: 'sa_user',
            password: '*******',
            server: 'DEDC',
            database: 'DEMO_BASE'
        }
        const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
        const req=await pool.connect()
        const conn = await req.request()
        return conn;
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
};


const createThumbnails = async() => {
    try{
        var conn = await getConn();
        const query = `exec DBBASE.get_client_info`
        var clientusers = await conn.query(query);
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}


createThumbnails()
```

How do I exactly call the function `getConn` inside `createThumbnails`. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't name it the same?

Comment: Name your variable `var getConn` something else.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using variable with the same name as the function.

Try different name:

```
var conn = await getConn();
const query = `exec DBBASE.get_client_info`
var clientusers = await conn.query(query);
```

Comment: I changed my variable to "conn". Now I am getting the error as "conn.query is not a function"

Comment: Well, that's different issue, since your `getConn()` can return either `req.request()` or `err`, so you'd need check for that.

Comment: Ya I am getting the error as "failed to connect to DEDC: 1433 - self signed certificate"

Answer (score 1):

You encounter what called [`hoisting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). Kyle Simpson has a [great explaination](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/8861041133f496edce0d03885e2e998d50c3414a/scope-closures/ch5.md#hoisting-declaration-vs-expression) on this topic

```
var getConn = await getConn();
```

which means `getConn` will be initialized first, before assignment, which equivalents to

```
var getConn // initialized
getConn = await getConn() // assignment
```

Then turned out that you got the error

Solution here is to store it in a different variable name, like

```
var conn = await getConn();
```

```js
async function getConn() {
  return {
    query: async () => {
      console.log("query called");
    },
  };
}

const createThumbnails = async () => {
  try {
    var conn = await getConn();
    const query = `exec DBBASE.get_client_info`;
    var clientusers = await conn.query(query);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

createThumbnails();
```

Comment: I changed my code. Now I am getting "conn.query is not a function"

Comment: @Saisri I think now it should be a problem in the result returned in `getConn` function itself. Please log the value before return to see what `conn` is

Comment: Ya it is returning the error as "failed to connect to DEDC: 1433 - self signed certificate"

Answer (score 0):

We need to use `trustServerCertificate: true` in DB configuration i.e in `const config`